# Null Pointer Exception on get Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm implementing the Google Map V2 api, and getting the current location. I have used exactly the same code as the Google sample project,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_map);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
    mLocationClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mLocationClient != null) {
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_AddFragment))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

My Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map_AddFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

when I run this code from the sample project it works, but when I copy this code to my project, it gives me a `Null pointer exception` on the line `mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_AddHTag))
                .getMap();`

I don't really know what's going on since It was working good, and still works just well in the sample project.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you adding the `SupportMapFragment` to the activity?

Comment: Try Project -> Clean. If you have moves stuff around in your XML files, this usually solves things.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you, I have updated my post. I have also cleaned the project, closed eclipse and re opened it and still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should be crashing with a `ClassCastException`. Your layout has `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`, and you are trying to cast that to `SupportMapFragment`, which will not work. If this is a `FragmentActivity`, you need to use `SupportMapFragment` in the layout as well as with your Java code.

Comment: Wow ! You're absolutely right ! I didn't even notice that... Thank you a lot !